# C++ OpenCV VideoWriter frame rate synchronization

Tags: c++, opencv

I am about to capture frames from a video grabber card. Those frames are processed and written to the HDD.
The whole setting is in a multithreading environment, so the grabber writes the images to a queue, and in another thread, the images is processed and another one writes to hdd. If the image is good by the definition of the processor, the image gets written to hdd. If 10 images in a row are "bad", the file is completed. If there are 9 images or less "bad", all the images get written with the next good image, so the file writer gets informed.

Here the problem, if I do not do it this way, instead writing each file directly after it is processed, the video file is fine, But 9 "bad" images are written. If I do it the way in my description above, the speed/frame rate of the video is not suitable. This description is a bit weird, so here is just a simplified example, so you can see the problem:

```
void FrameWriter::writeFrameLoop() {

    string path = getPath();
    cv::Size2i size(1350, 1080);
    cv::VideoWriter videoWriter(path, fourcc, 30, size);

    while (this->isRunning) {

        while (!this->frames.empty()) {
        
            usleep(100000); // this effects the speed/frame
            videoWriter.write(this->pop());
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }

    videoWriter.release();
}
```

The example is pretty simple, here I "block" the writing process with a sleep, remember this is a different thread. This means after the capturing is stopped, the file writing takes a bit longer.
But I would expect that this does not effect the video itself, because there is a framerate of 30 and the images are still in the same order. But for me it seems to effect the video file, when I call "videoWriter.write" not in time. In this case the video is much faster than expected.
I thought only the configured frames of 30 and the count of written images would effect the video speed, but it is not. Can anyone help me do understand what is going on here?

I am using openCV 4.4.0 with Ubuntu 18.04.
Thank you for your help.
BR Michael

Comment: I're you saying that if you call `videoWriter.write()` e.g. 1000 times per second, then resulting video will be playing very fast? So video writer doesn't respect FPS of 30 provided in constructor?

Comment: The opposite, I call the videoWriter.write() only 10 times a second and then the video is faster. But you are right, it doesn't respect the fps of 30. Or at least I have no idea what is going on

Comment: There's [getBackendNam()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a1dced14e3773cc1239972342afc274fc) method that tells what backend is used (like `FFMPEG`), it could be the issue with this backend only. There should be also methods to change it to some other popular ones.

Comment: I think I know what problem is. You're saying that you call `write()` exactly 10 times per second, meaning 10 frames. Also you're getting these 10 frames as I expect from real time data of some grabbing card. And you're writing just these 10 frames through `write()`. But for CV library you told that video is 30 frames per second. Meaning that your 10 writes are actually filling data for 1/3 of second. Hence video should be 3 times faster, each 1 second of video plays 3 seconds of grabbed video. Just set 10 for FPS rate in vide writer's constructor instead of 30, or duplicate 3 times each frame

Comment: I created [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180978/941531) with more details on thing that I've said above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my problem and it was me, not OpenCV.
Because of the multithreading environment, I was writing the images (cv::Mat) to a queue. Since there are a lot of transformations YUV -> RGB -> BGR -> Crop etc. I was expecting the cv::Mat object I put in the queue was a deep copy. Instead of this, the cv::Mat was always the same object. Which means, even if there was already 20 cv::Mat entries in my queue, all of them was the same and all of them "changed" when ever there was a new image.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know the reason of fast-playing result videos.

In constructor `cv::VideoWriter videoWriter(path, fourcc, 30, size);` you set frame rate (FPS) of resulting video to 30. It means that CV library expects exactly 30 frames to be written by `write()` function for each 1 second of resulting video stream.

Also for CV library there's no difference how fast you call `write()` with new frame, you may call it 5 times per second or 10 or even 1000 times. The only thing that matters is that you have to provide exactly 30 frames for each second of video, and how fast you provide these 30 frames doesn't matter.

I mean that all your `sleep(...)` functionality doesn't matter for CV VideoWriter class. And it is always true for all video rendering/conversion libraries. So pausing thread doesn't change anything at all.

But in your case you're saying that you grab 10 frames per second from real-time video data of your grabber's video card. It means the your FPS is really 10 frames per second. So in order to solve your task correctly next things should be done:

1. Remove all pausing functionality, like calling `sleep()`. It is not needed at all. And doesn't change behavior of VideoWriter.
2. Then first way to solve the task is to change in your constructor `cv::VideoWriter videoWriter(path, fourcc, 30, size);` value 30 to 10. This already will solve your task, but you have to be sure that you grab 10 frames per second, not more not less. Then your video will be a correctly playing (correct speed) video with a frame rate of 10 frames per second. This is the simplest solution. Video doesn't need to be 30 FPS for correctly playing later, 10 FPS video will be correctly played later by any player.
3. Another solution, if you really want your resulting video to play 30 frames per second, not less, not more, then duplicate each frame of your grabbed video three times, thus you'll get 30 frames out of 10 frames of your grabbed video. By duplicating I just mean that you should call `videWriter.write(...)` three times (in a small loop) with same single frame, call this `write` without any pause (like `sleep`). Then again your resulting video will have exactly 30 frames per second.

I think you just miss understood how `CV::VideoWriter` works. You thought that `write()` renders resulting video in real time, meaning that if you feed it 10 frames but exactly within one second period, then it should render correct speed of video. But this writer renders video not in real time, meaning that it just supposes that 10 frames passed constitute just 1/3 of second of resulting videos, hence it expects 30 frames to be written for 1 resulting second.

Comment: No I understood the videoWriter right, I was expecting when I write 30 images a seconds, the result should be the same like writing this 30 images within 2 minutes. So only the configured fps should matter. And it is exactly like that, see my post to understand what I did wrong

Comment: @user2267367 Very strange, I always thought that any video conversion/rendering routines should be offline, meaning they will render same video output regardless of speed of feeding frames. Then sorry, good that you actually found the [right solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64205483/941531).

Comment: It does, it is acting like expected but because of the multithread environment and my messed up deep copy it did not work. So it was just my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a camera that's not able to provide a constant frame rate of let's say 30 frames, you can also consider limiting the frame rate yourself to e.g. 25 and measure the time elapsed since writing the last frame. You can also change your framerate to arbitrary values, as long as the camera is able to provide it. An example of an implementation:

```
m_fps = 25;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point now;

while (1) {

    now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(now - start).count();
    
    if ((double)duration > (1e9 / m_fps)) {

        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        
        m_duration += duration;

        // Capture frame-by-frame
        if(m_cap->grab()) { m_cap->retrieve(m_frame); }

        // write frame
        m_writer->write(m_frame);
        cv::waitKey(1);

    }
}
```